# How to evaluate stop criterion with vector and real number?

Tags: linear-algebra

I  have the following stopping criterion in my algorithm $|\nabla f(x_i)| ^2\leq \epsilon $.
First of all does the left side mean that I have to take an absolute value of the gradient of function f and put it to the 2nd power? If so, my left side is a vector [$x_o, y_0$] how do I compare $\epsilon = 0.5$ with vector?

Comment: Some authors write $| x |^2$ for the Euclidean norm of a vectpr $x$, so you should compare the squared norm of your gradient with $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am implementing it in Python and I am not sure. So to evaluate the left side of the inequality should I apply the Pythagorean theorem to vector  to calulcate the  distance from the origin? Am I right?